# Can you use variables as descendant selectors in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to figure out how to make selectors, like descendant selectors, in Jquery using variables.

I know you can add variables using .add(), but I havent' been able to figure out how to narrow a selection using them.

Here's what I've been playing with:

```js
//descendant selector using classnames:
$("div.aReallyLongClassName li.anotherReallyLongClassName").css({background:"red"});

//Using the jquery below doesn't work, but the console displays the classnames exactly how they appear in the jquery above.
var foo = 'div.aReallyLongClassName';
var bar = 'li.anotherReallyLongClassName';
$("#console").html('"' + foo + ' ' + bar + '"');
$('"' + foo + ' ' + bar + '"').css({background:"green"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aReallyLongClassName">
    <ul>
        <li>No background</li>
        <li class="anotherReallyLongClassName">Red BG = Fail, Green BG = Success!</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="foobar">
    <ul>
        <li>No background</li>
        <li class="anotherReallyLongClassName">No background</li>
    </ul>
</div>
Computed selector is:
<span id="console"></span>
```

How can I select descendants using variables in Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many quotes

```
$(foo + ' ' + bar).css({background:"green"});
```

will do. Your snippet updated and green:

```js
//descendant selector using classnames:
$("div.aReallyLongClassName li.anotherReallyLongClassName").css({background:"red"});

//Using the jquery below doesn't work, but the console displays the classnames exactly how they appear in the jquery above.
var foo = 'div.aReallyLongClassName';
var bar = 'li.anotherReallyLongClassName';
$("#console").html('"' + foo + ' ' + bar + '"');
$(foo + ' ' + bar).css({background:"green"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aReallyLongClassName">
    <ul>
        <li>No background</li>
        <li class="anotherReallyLongClassName">Red BG = Fail, Green BG = Success!</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="foobar">
    <ul>
        <li>No background</li>
        <li class="anotherReallyLongClassName">No background</li>
    </ul>
</div>
Computed selector is:
<span id="console"></span>
```

Comment: Probably should have thought to try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 $("#console").html('"' + foo + ' ' + bar + '"');
```

to this:

```
 $("#console").append(foo.html());
 $("#console").append(bar.html());
```

or to this:

```
$("#console").html(foo.html() + bar.html());
```

Otherwise, you will attach strings (such as `div.aReallyLongClassName`) to `$("#console")`.

Alternatively, you can create jquery objects and use them like this:

```
var foo = $('div.aReallyLongClassName');
var bar = $('li.anotherReallyLongClassName');

$("#console").append(foo);
$("#console").append(bar);

foo.css({background:"green"});

bar.css({background:"green"});
```

Comment: "Otherwise, you will attach strings" - that's what the OP intended to do here, presumably for debug purposes. And your `css()` code is setting a background on both `foo` and `bar` where the OP wanted it on a `bar` within a `foo`